# Azure Blob Storage: Change Feed vs Events

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Azure offers two mechanisms for detecting changes:

- [Change Feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-change-feed?tabs=azure-portal)
- [Storage Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview)

I didn't find a comparison of those two mechanism: for me it is unclear when to use which mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me guide you on this the change Feed provides an ordered, guaranteed, and durable log of all the changes that occur to blobs in your storage account.
Best suited for scenarios where you need a comprehensive log of changes and want to process changes in a specific order.

where Storage Events are notifications that are triggered in response to specific events occurring on a blob container.
it is best suited for scenarios where you need real-time notifications about specific events ex- blob creation, deletion etc,it is useful for building event-driven architectures where you want to trigger actions or workflows in response to specific blob-related events.
For a detailed analysis follow the link below it takes you to the azure documentation,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=Change%20Feed

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=Storage%20Events